# Can't Subtract Paint From Part of Mesh

Tags: weight-painting

Hey I have a mesh of a deer. I'm currently weight painting it. As you can see from the images below, if I select the left leg there is some paint on the right leg, which means when the left leg moves, a piece of the right leg moves too. If I try subtracting it off with the brush, all that happens is paint from the left leg gets subtracted and the right leg paint remains. I don't have x mirror on either.

Blend File: [image]

How can I remove the paint from the right leg?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this happens when you start building your mesh with a mirror modifier and forget to apply the modifier BEFORE applying the armature to the mesh. Just go back to the point before applying the mesh, apply mirror modifier so you have only on mesh and try again.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. I'll try this if I run into the issue again, Wasn't expecting anyone to reply to this after so much time haha